# How to use Wladm command?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am working extended App authenticity, I see I have to use Wladm command to create a .wlapp file.. But I am not sure how to use it on windows command line. Do I need to install it or will it come with MFP CLI. please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this documentation topic: [Configuring extended app authenticity checking](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/r_enabling_extended_authenticity_checking.html)

> To enable extended authenticity checking, you must deploy a modified .wlapp file, instead of the original .wlapp file that is generated by the build process. To obtain the modified .wlapp file, use one of the following > two facilities:
>
> - The enable-extended-authenticity command of the wladm Ant task, as described in Commands for apps.
> - The enable extended-authenticity command of the wladm program, as described in Commands for apps.

You produce the wlapp as you always do. You then apply on that original .wlapp the wladm process, which modifies the .wlapp file. You then deploy the modified .wlapp file.

Both the ant path and wladm tool are available in from your production installation of MobileFirst Platform.

Comment: Is there any possibility I can download wladm tool separately.

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Thanks for the input Idan.